# How to get the vaadin-context-menu demo to work?

Tags: polymer, vaadin, web-component, polymer-2.x, vaadin-core-elements

[Here is the `vaadin-context-menu` documentation page](https://vaadin.com/elements/-/element/vaadin-context-menu#docs).

On that page, there is a button labeled <kbd>TRY IT OUT</kbd> [that links to a demo page here](https://jsbin.com/yihupap/1/edit?html,output).

My problem is that I can't get the demo page to actually do anything. I see no errors in the console.

Is the problem on my end? Or is there something wrong with the demo? If it's the latter, how can I fix the code to get the demo to work?

Please show the solution in a working jsBin or Codepen.

https://jsbin.com/yihupap/1/edit?html,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>vaadin-context-menu demo</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.vaadin.com/vaadin-core-elements/master/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="https://cdn.vaadin.com/vaadin-core-elements/master/vaadin-context-menu/vaadin-context-menu.html">

  <!-- import paper-menu and paper-item -->
  <link rel="import" href="https://cdn.vaadin.com/vaadin-core-elements/master/paper-listbox/paper-listbox.html">
  <link rel="import" href="https://cdn.vaadin.com/vaadin-core-elements/master/paper-item/paper-item.html">
</head>
<body>

<vaadin-context-menu>
  <template>
    <paper-listbox>
      <paper-item>First menu item</paper-item>
      <paper-item>Second menu item</paper-item>
    </paper-listbox>
  </template>

  <p>This paragraph has the context menu provided in the above template.</p>
  <p>Another paragraph with the context menu.</p>
</vaadin-context-menu>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Using those jsbin links, I get a semi-transparent context menu when right clicking the paragraphs in Chrome 59.0.3071.115, so I'd suspect something on your end.

Comment: Works for me as well.  Did you right click on the first paragraph.

Comment: the working examples are here : https://vaadin.com/elements/-/element/vaadin-context-menu#demos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is actually with JSBin and Safari.  I cant even get the darn page to load in Safari (Version 10.1.1 12603.2.4).

But the main demo page does work in safari, chrome, etc:
http://vaadin.com/elements/-/element/vaadin-context-menu#demos

Use that instead.

As requested here is a working codepen using the same example in your question : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MozOxG

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>vaadin-context-menu demo</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.vaadin.com/vaadin-core-elements/master/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="https://cdn.vaadin.com/vaadin-core-elements/master/vaadin-context-menu/vaadin-context-menu.html">

  <!-- import paper-menu and paper-item -->
  <link rel="import" href="https://cdn.vaadin.com/vaadin-core-elements/master/paper-listbox/paper-listbox.html">
  <link rel="import" href="https://cdn.vaadin.com/vaadin-core-elements/master/paper-item/paper-item.html">
</head>
<body>

<vaadin-context-menu>
  <template>
    <paper-listbox>
      <paper-item>First menu item</paper-item>
      <paper-item>Second menu item</paper-item>
    </paper-listbox>
  </template>

  <p>This paragraph has the context menu provided in the above template.</p>
  <p>Another paragraph with the context menu.</p>
</vaadin-context-menu>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

*Edit: @petey points out in a comment that this answer only applies when trying to run `vaadin-context-menu` from jsBin. So the problem might be between jsBin and Safari and not Vaadin and Safari.*

## This answer only applies to JSBin.

It works in Chrome. But not on Safari. (Running macOS Sierra v.10.12.5.)

`vaadin-context-menu`

```
Browser  Support
-------  -------
Chrome     ✅
Safari     ❌
```

Safari apparently does not support `vaadin-context-menu` at this time. Below are screen recordings using Safari then Chrome.

*(Note: In the below recordings: 
Green circles indicate a right click.
Black circles indicate a left click.)*

## Safari ❌

v10.1.1 (12603.2.4):

[image]

## Chrome ✅

v59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit):

[image]

Comment: This is not accurate! the main demos page works in Safari (Version 10.1.1 12603.2.4) just fine: https://vaadin.com/elements/-/element/vaadin-context-menu#demos  Something must be goofy with JSBin & safari but not vaadin & safari.

Comment: @petey: I can confirm: [I got the demos to work correctly in Safari](http://vaadin.com/elements/-/element/vaadin-context-menu#demos). I agree, the problem is most likely something between jsBin and Safari. I edited my answer accordingly. My apologies to all the Vaadin engineers. You do great work.